# How can I reformat a Twitter RSS feed?

Tags: android, twitter, rss

For example, if I wanted to strip 'google' (title or content) from the beginning of this feed for use in an android application -

https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/20536157.rss

Any ideas? Simple implementations?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather simply with bash/sed:

```
wget https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/20536157.rss -O -| sed 's/<title>google: /<title>/g'
```

can also be saved to a file:

```
wget https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/20536157.rss -O -| sed 's/<title>google: /<title>/g' > 20536157-mini.rss
```